# How to create a recent news list based on current news

Tags: orchardcms

I'm working on Orchard 1.10. The goal is to design a news website based on it. I have a problem that has not been solved.
That is how to generate a recent news list along with a news which I currently view in detail. I mean when I select a news, I need to show other news which has an Id lower than current news's ID along with it.

Any suggests are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: So you need to show the latest news (in a widget)? Sounds almost the same as the RecentBlogPostWidget

Comment: I agree it does, but it show all posts including the current post. I want the list will be exactly older than current post when viewing in detail.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty basic implementation of a custom module with a widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom part and attach it to the News content type. Something like this:

```
public class RecentNewsPart : ContentPart {

}

public class RecentNewsPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<RecentNewsPart> {
    private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;
    public RecentNewsPartDriver(IContentManager contentManager) {
        _contentManager = contentManager;
    }

    protected override DriverResult Display(RecentNewsPart part, string displayType, dynamic shapeHelper) {
        return ContentShape("Parts_RecentNewsPart", () => {
            // or however the date is stored on your news,
            // maybe just the CommonPart CreatedUtc
            var currentNewsPart = part.As<NewsPart>();
            var currentNewsDate = currentNewsPart.Date;

            var recentNews = _contentManager
                .Query<NewsPart, NewsPartRecord>("News")
                .Where(c => c.Date < currentNewsDate)
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.Date)
                .Slice(0, 10)
                .ToList();

            return shapeHelper.Parts_RecentNewsPart(Items: recentNews);
        });
    }
```

Placement.info:

```
<Match ContentType="News">
    <Place Parts_RecentNewsPart="/AsideSecond:3" />
</Match>
```

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you very much